# I have a problem with function mouseeneter

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

Hello please why if I hover on`<li>` from `<ul class='menu controls'>` change background but not change color. I know that `.controls a` have color and it is more than `class color for li` but if I want `addClass for <a>` dont work it if i change `var li = $(".controls").find('li'); to var li = $(".controls").find('a');` so this dont work why ?
https://codepen.io/Lukinezko/pen/qBOJEad

Comment: I know that I can make in CSS but now I want learn JS

Comment: Please add the code to SO so that it can be referenced in the future (sometimes links break). This also makes the question clearer and easier to answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.selected a {
   color: white;
}
```

By the way, you can do this completely with css without js! with just 2-3 lines of css codes..